# Ruby class subclassed from Sinatra::Base has private methods but they disappear in irb console

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need to access some functionality in some private methods in a Ruby class that is subclassed from Sinatra::Base.

The class definition begins like this:

```
class Geminabox < Sinatra::Base
```

it begins with a series of code blocks like this:

```
  get '/' do
    @gems = load_gems
    @index_gems = index_gems(@gems)
    erb :index
  end
```

where 'load_gems' and 'index_gems' are private methods defined later in the same class.

However, if I load this class into an irb console and create an instance like this:

```
 g=Geminabox.new
```

and then try to view the private methods I get this:

```
> 2.2.1 :005 > g.private_methods(false)  
=> [:initialize] 
> 2.2.1 :006 >
```

there is no 'load_gems', no 'index_gems', etc., etc. and I can't call any of them using 'send':

```
2.2.1 :007 > g.send(:load_gems)
NoMethodError: undefined method `load_gems' for #<Geminabox app_file="/apps/geminabox/lib/geminabox.rb">
    from (irb):7
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.1 :008 >
```

I don't understand why and I am hoping someone can enlighten me.

Comment: g.class returns Sinatra::Wrapper and this class dont have private methods. If you need Base private methods try Geminabox.superclass

Answer (score 5):

The eigenclass of `Sinatra::Base` overrides [`new`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1486).

You might check that `Geminabox.new` actually returns an instance of `Sinatra::Wrapper`:

```
Class.new(Sinatra::Base).new.class
#⇒ Sinatra::Wrapper
```

To get what you want, use:

```
Geminabox.private_instance_methods false
```